# Solving the Diophantine system of equations $w + x + y - z = a, wx + yz = b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

If we have a Diophantine system of equations of the form

$$
\begin{align*}
x + y & = a, \\
xy & = b
\end{align*}  \tag{1}
$$

with $x,y$ unknown and $a,b$ known, we could solve it using the identity

$$
\begin{align}
(x-y)^2 & = (x+y)^2 -4(xy)  \\
        & = a^2 - 4b
\end{align} \tag{2}
$$

The Diophantine system of equations has a solution iff $a^2 - 4b = k^2$ is a perfect square, for some integer $k$ where $k+a$ is even. We can then solve $x-y = k, x+y=a$ to solve for $x, y$.

While working on a problem, I have obtained a system of equations of the following form:

$$
\begin{align}
w + x + y - z & = a \\
wx + yz & = b
\end{align} \tag{3}
$$

This looks tantalizingly close to the form of Eqn. (1) with a twist and I am not able to proced further.

Is there a way to find parametric solutions for $w, x, y, z$ in Eqn. (3)?

Comment: System (1) doesn't look like a diophantine at all. 2 unknowns and 2 equations. One can obtain a quadratic for the variables and solve for them. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Hersh System (1) is solvable as mentioned in the question and as pointed out by you. System (3) is what I am looking to solve.

Comment: Eliminate $z$, then $(3) \implies (x + y - a) (w + y) =b - a w$. Let $w$ paremetr, then find $x,y$ from factors $b - a w$.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov OP has clearly mentioned that w is an unknown so we don't know the factors of $b-aw$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment: Does this idea help you:

For example we want to solve following system of equations:

$\begin{cases} x+w+y-z=2\\xw+yz=14\end{cases}$

Suppose:

$w=x+d_1, y=x+d_2, z=x+d_3$

we have:

$x+w+y-z=x+(x+d_1)+(x+d_2)-(x+d_3)=2x+(d_1+d_2-d_3)=2$

$x(x+d_1)+ (x+d_2)(x+d_3)=2x^2+(d_1+d_2+d_3)x+d_2\cdot d_3=14$

So problem reduces to:

$\begin{cases}2x+(d_1+d_2-d_3)=2\\2x^2+(d_1+d_2+d_3)x+d_2\cdot d_3=14\end{cases}$

take for example $x=1$ , we have:

$\begin{cases}(d_1+d_2-d_3)=0\\d_1+d_2+d_3+d_2\cdot d_3=12\end{cases}$

So we get:

$2d_3+d_2d_3=d_3(2+d_2)=12=3\times 4=2\times 6$

take for instance $d_3=3$, this gives $d_2=2$ and $d_1=1$; so solutions are:

$(x, w, y, z)=(1, 2, 3, 4)$

Comment: This is good and helps me move forward. I have accepted the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$wx+yz=b$

$w+x+y-z=a$

Above simultaneous equation has more than one

parametrization:

For '$w$'=$12$, we have:

$(a,b)=[(12m),(m^3)]$

$(x,y,z)=[(m^2+11m-132),(132-m^2),(12-m)]$

And for $m=8$ we get numerical solution:

$(w,x,y,z,a,b)=(12,20,68,4,96,512)$